# The type or namespace name 'WebUI' does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

[image]I have created below WebBasePage class in my Web Application with Visual Studio 2013 (first time in VS2013).

```
namespace WebApp1.WebUI
{
    public class WebBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to derive above base class in one of my web page (as shown below)...

```
namespace WebApp1.Errors 
{
    public partial class Error : WebApp1.WebUI.WebBasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error at below line:

**Line**: "public partial class Error : WebApp1.WebUI.WebBasePage"

**Error**: The type or namespace name 'WebUI' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApp1' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This code has been working in VS2012, not sure what's wrong with VS2013.

Comment: Is there a class and folder named WebUI in the same project?  Also all your projects are having same .NET version?

Comment: There is no WebUI folder. WebBasePage class is inside App_Code folder with WebApp1.WebUI as namespace. The Web App is using .NET 4.5 and is the only project I have in this solution. Not sure if StackOverflow has attachment ability, if so I can attach this solution.

Comment: Check the references in that case. Also, you can use imgur to upload screenshot

Comment: Here is the link to the solution, zipped and shared on my google drive - [WebApp1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxLEvLuvBj2aaEpSQ2tmT0w3YTBKTDNCdWI5cmJMYjdnUkZB/edit?usp=docslist_api)

Comment: why do you have a sub namespace `WebUI` in the first place? The `WebApp1` namespace seems to imply you're already in a "WebUI" environment. I know this isn't an answer, but maybe you should go a little less heavy on the namespaces.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks Punit, i was able to add image for an error to the main post. Also, its a brand new web app and all the references are fine. The class WebBasePage and Error.aspx page were added after new web app project was created.

Comment: Thanks @DLeh, I just removed "WebUI" from the namespace but still was giving error. Playing with namespace, I created "WebUI" folder and moved my class from "App_Code" folder to "WebUI" folder, didn't help too. Then I deleted WebBasePage class and added brand new class under "WebUI" folder, which automatically gave a namespace WebApp1.WebUI to the class, and this time it did work for me!!!

Comment: try closing visual studio and deleting your solution's `.suo` file. This kind of weirdness can happen sometimes with those files.

Comment: @DLeh, thanks again and certainly weird. Deleting .sou file and re-opening solution didn't help too.

Sounds like Visual Studio 2013 is looking for the actual Folder created inside Web App, for all the namespaces, before it can be used in any classes. This wasn't an issue with VS2012, so wondering if there are any settings (under tools - options) which can tell VS2013 that you dont really need to look for actual folders :)

Comment: can you check the properties on the `WebBasePage.cs` to ensure that the build action is set to "Compile"?

Comment: @DLeh, Yes yes yes, that was it!!! So, when you add new class under App_Code folder, the default Build Action property value is "Content" instead of "Compile". When I set to "Compile" it worked like a charm!!!

Comment: @DLeh, Please create an answer and i will mark it as useful. thanks!

Comment: i have submitted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the "build action" in the properties pane on the problematic file is set to "Compile". Otherwise Visual Studio will not build the file and won't see the namespace or types defined in that file.